# Convert/Export shapefile to *.dat

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, export

I have a shapefile (either polygon or polyline) that I need to convert to an "Area Data" .dat file to use with another program (it's already older, it says it wants "ArcInfo Format").

I've tried Googling and playing around with the different export functions, but so far I haven't had any luck.

I'm fairly new to working with ArcGIS. I have ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 and the other program I need to load the map to is a very specialized program for theodolite tracking, Pythagoras (http://www.cetaecoresearch.com/research-software-pythagoras.html).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please [edit] your question to include a little more information - what version of ArcGIS are you using, what other program are you trying to export to (including version).

Comment: Have you tested "Export Feature Attribute to ASCII" in Spatial Statistics Tools.

Comment: The Pythagoras manual says about the ArcInfo .dat file: "An ungenerated Arc Info data file with a series of longitude
and latitude points of selected trackline(s)." I wonder if it's in the format used by the "generate" command. [GDAL](http://courses.washington.edu/gis250/lessons/data_export/index.html#generate) can handle them I think.

Answer (score 1):

Read the 'importing data' section of the manual, found on page 54.  Here's the manual:  http://www.cetaecoresearch.com/Software/Pythagoras/Pythagoras_manual.pdf

It states that you can import excel data.  I recommend exporting your GIS data to csv, open in excel, save as excel doc, import to pythagoras.

If you have programming skills you may be able write a script to convert GIS data to the pythagoras metafile format.